# Configure a Magento site with GIT connected to BitBucket throught an SSH connection

Tags: git, magento, ssh, bitbucket

I'm developing a new Magento and I need to install GIT as version control, but I'm pretty new using GIT, so I'm trying to find a way to complete this integration.

I have two environments created: Stage which is hosted on a sub-domain (example: stage.domain.com) and Production which is hosted on the main domain (example: domain.com) Both environments are identical, both have the same files and database.

What I want is to be able to deploy new changes as follows:

- connect to Stage site via SSH connection, create new "feature branch" as feature/[branch-name], make desire changes, add and commit these changes to this new branch.
- push this new branch into origin, which would be the remote repository created on Bitbucket (git push origin feature/[branch_name])
- checkout "develop branch", do git pull, merge origin/feature/[branch-name] into develop, and push these changes.
- checkout "master branch", do git pull, merge origin/develop into master, and push these changes.

After doing these 4 steps, Master branch would be updated with the new changes, so after that, all I want to do is to connect to Production site via SSH connection and just do:

git status
git pull

That would be all, this the way I'm handling a deployment process for another client that I have(but I wasn't the one who configured it), so I just want to use this same "work-flow" for this new Magento site that I'm developing.

It would be great if someone can share a step by step guide in how to complete this integration from scratch(installing GIT, running specific commands, cloning remote repository, etc...)

I will appreciate your help on this.
Thanks!

Comment: simply create a git repo and start commit code over it , git commands does not vari from platform of code you are writing on

Answer (score 1):

I have solved the problem. I have initiated Git on production, I have pushed it to the remote repository, then initiated Git on Stage and I have cloned it from the remote repository, that was all. I have a guide with the correct commands in case someone needs it.

Comment: You could edit your answer to include those commands: that would help others.

Answer (score 0):

Install GIT
For window:
Install GIT software from one of the below URLs.
https://git-scm.com/download/win
https://www.sourcetreeapp.com/

For Ubuntu:
sudo apt-get install git

Configure GIT account on your system
Open git command console and run two commands. Replace email and username of your git in the command.
git config –global user.email “email address”
git config –global user.name “password”

Clone GIT branch
This is the first command to initialize the project

Go to GitHub
Go to branch from where you want to clone
Click on ‘clone or download’ button
Copy ‘clone with https’ URL e.g. https://github.com/……../…….git
Create a directory on your system and go to the new directory
Run under command:
git clone https://github.com/……../…….git

GIT checkout
You can switch one branch to another branch
eg. git checkout dev[branch name]
git checkout design

GIT Add
You can add file to GIT
git add.

GIT commit
git commit -m ‘added files’

GIT Push
Push the branch on git :
git push origin [name_of_your_new_branch]
eg. git push origin dev

GIT Pull
Pull the changes from git to your system :
git pull

GIT Remove
git rm filename
Please don’t remove file or folder without git commands.

List Branches
You can see all branches created by using :
git branch

GIT Status
This is the very very useful command, so you can use this command before using any command to know exactly where are you. To heck updated code and also confirmation of which branch you stand
git status

Git command for testing with sequence
– git init
– git clone
– git checkout branch_name
– Add test file like test.txt
– git add.
– git commit -m ‘add test file’
– git push origin branch_name
– Put username and password of git when asked
– Check new added test.txt file on branch of git